# Swift 3 - Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary, nsindexpath

I upgraded my project to Swift 3 and came across this error:

```
let cellDescriptor = cellDescriptors[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section][indexOfVisibleRow] as! [String: AnyObject]
```

I got an error on this line:

```
Type 'Any' has no subscript members
```

How exactly do I fix this? I'm not sure how to go about it. I tried converted the first part to an NSDictionary, then it tells me that `indexPath` of type `IndexPath` cannot be converted to `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: what type is cellDescriptors? its not recognizing it as an array.

Comment: Give us more details about cellDescriptors. It's likely that the compiler cannot infer the second type, since you're using subscript twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIndexPath has been replaced with IndexPath, so that part should become simply

```
cellDescriptors[indexPath.section]
```

For the rest of the problem, how have you defined cellDescriptors?  It may be easier to do this as a two-step process

```
let firstPart = cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as! MyCellDescriptor
let cellDescriptor = firstPart[indexOfVisibleRow]
```

Comment: While this is true, doesn't fix the current problem.